# getting data from server with NSURLConnection showing in TableView

Tags: ios, ios7, get, nsurlconnection

I am getting didFailWithError Please help me

```
 scanCode = @"123";
    NSString * urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://1-dot-digiphoto-01.appspot.com/v1/service/rest/getAlbums/QR/{%@}",scanCode];



NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (!conn)
{
    responseData = nil;
    NSLog(@"Connection Error");

}
```

Comment: i want to send scanCode Sitring is {123, UK111, IND111, USA111,}

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference but you do not need the curly brackets {} in NSString stringWithFormat you can leave like this: `NSString * urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://1-dot-digiphoto-01.appspot.com/v1/service/rest/getAlbums/QR/%@",scanCode];`

Comment: @urnotsam we can use curly brackets for query string.He Missed to sent content mode. Once he set content mode like below my answer it must work.

Comment: @PREMKUMAR You're right my bad.  You answer below is correct I will up vote it for other people in the future with similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://1-dot-digiphoto-01.appspot.com/v1/service/rest/getAlbums/QR/{%@}",@"123"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[theRequest addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( connection )
{
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}
```